# Kubernetes 1.8.10 kube-apiserver priorityclasses error

Tags: kubernetes, kops

New cluster 1.8.10 spinned with kops.

In K8S 1.8 there is a new feature `Pod Priority and Preemption`.
More information: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/pod-priority-preemption/#how-to-use-priority-and-preemption

`kube-apiserver` is logging errors

> I0321 16:27:50.922589       7 wrap.go:42] GET
>   /apis/admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1alpha1/initializerconfigurations:
>   (140.067µs) 404 [[kube-apiserver/v1.8.10 (linux/amd64)
>   kubernetes/044cd26] 127.0.0.1:47500] I0321 16:27:51.257756       7
>   wrap.go:42] GET
>   /apis/scheduling.k8s.io/v1alpha1/priorityclasses?resourceVersion=0:
>   (168.391µs) 404 [[kube-apiserver/v1.8.10 (linux/amd64)
>   kubernetes/044cd26] 127.0.0.1:47500] E0321 16:27:51.258176       7
>   reflector.go:205]
>   k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/client/informers/informers_generated/internalversion/factory.go:73:
>   Failed to list *scheduling.PriorityClass: the server could not find
>   the requested resource (get priorityclasses.scheduling.k8s.io)

I quite not understand why. No one should access it as it's not even enabled yet (it's alpha).

No pod is using `priorityClassName`.

Running explain:

> kubectl explain priorityclass error: API version:
>   scheduling.k8s.io/v1alpha1 is not supported by the server. Use one of:
>   [apiregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1 extensions/v1beta1 apps/v1beta1
>   apps/v1beta2 authentication.k8s.io/v1
>   authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1 authorization.k8s.io/v1
>   authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1 autoscaling/v1 autoscaling/v2beta1
>   batch/v1 batch/v1beta1 certificates.k8s.io/v1beta1
>   networking.k8s.io/v1 policy/       v1beta1
>   rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1 rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
>   storage.k8s.io/v1 storage.k8s.io/v1beta1 apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
>   v1]

Is this normal or `kops` specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is related to that Kops option in its config (`kops get --name $NAME -oyaml`):

```
kubeAPIServer:
  runtimeConfig:
    admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1alpha1: "true"
```

Anyway, all components working thru the API server and it is not a surprise that sometimes based on configuration it is trying to call some disable features. At least it has to check which APIs a supported, so why :)

So, I think you don't need to worry about it, that is the configuration-related message. Don't worry about it. Or just enable that feature, it will solve warning messages.

Comment: Mine kops cluster config doesn't have this enabled.
```
  kubeAPIServer:
    authorizationRbacSuperUser: admin
```

Comment: So, you can enable that features and it will resolve warning messages.  Or you can just ignore them.

Comment: Thanks man. Do you know a way to know which component sent this API request? I've tried to run `kube-apiserver` with loglevel=4, no luck. Do I have to sniff traffic to check it out?

Comment: All components in a cluster connected thru an API server, so all of them sending a lot of requests.

Comment: Yeah I know. But I would love to pinpoint one sending this specific one. Any ideas?

Comment: The only one idea which I have - searching that in the source code. But, you can make one trick - run something like nginx as a proxy for an API server and send all requests thru it, it has lovely logs.