# Kubernetes audit log showing 404 not found on event

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm seeing the following log continuously in the Kubernetes audit log file.
Can anyone explain what is this error and its reason

```
{
"kind":"Event",
"apiVersion":"audit.k8s.io/v1beta1",
"metadata":{"creationTimestamp":"2018-08-29T06:59:04Z"},
"level":"Request",
"timestamp":"2018-08-29T06:59:04Z",
"auditID":"97187fc8-76c1-42f0-9435-c11928b6ec49",
"stage":"ResponseComplete",
"requestURI":"/apis/admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1alpha1/initializerconfigurations",
"verb":"list",
"user":{"username":"system:apiserver","uid":"44rrd678-859a-4f663-bt79-23bar678uj66","groups":["system:masters"]},
"sourceIPs":["X.X.X.X"],
"objectRef":{"resource":"initializerconfigurations","apiGroup":"admissionregistration.k8s.io","apiVersion":"v1alpha1"},
"responseStatus":{"metadata":{},"status":"Failure","reason":"NotFound","code":404},
"requestReceivedTimestamp":"2018-08-29T06:59:04.350346Z",
"stageTimestamp":"2018-08-29T06:59:04.350425Z",
"annotations":{"authorization.k8s.io/decision":"allow","authorization.k8s.io/reason":""}
}
```

Comment: Possibly relevant is https://stackoverflow.com/a/49424965/9705485 and the comments on it

Comment: @RyanDawson Thanks Ryan for the update. Yes it seems so. My understanding is that "initializers" is an alpha feature and is disabled by default. The 404 errors is because audit handler trying to call this disable feature.